# How to manage custom filters setup

Tags: filter

I need to redesign an app in which User can customize the visibility of filters and sources. At the moment, you select sources in one panel and select their corresponding filters in another. Based on User research, I decided to move the sources and filters to the same place. The problem is the business requirement: it should all be visible on one page! So let's say we have three sources: Books, Films, and Ebooks. Each of the sources has a set of specific filters. But, there are also some general filters. [image]

At the moment you select the source via checkbox, then you can set the visibility of filters with toggle switch. Via the cog icon you set the boosting of a given source.

I hate this solution because we're mixing filters with sources. I prepared a design in which filters and sources are in different pages and you select them independently - the problem is that when you select a source specific filter, you don't know if this source is on or off (and they cannot change the backend). The design was rejected. I prepared another one with two cards in which the main filters are on one card, the sources are on the other. On the sources card I used progressive disclosure: you select sources you want to search within and then the filters associated with it appear and you can set them then. It was rejected because it was too "stiff" and there was too much clicking.

Do you have any idea what can I do to improve this setting so that Users understand it?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to redesign it, it's probably good to simplify the interface. You can consider adopting an indeterminate checkbox kind of design as shown in this sample below.

[image: picture showing the appearance of partial checks, full and empty checkboxes]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a very neat example. Thank you! I would do it this way if I could. Thing is... I need to differentiate between adding sources to search within (e.g. Toppings, Cheese), and filters (Cheddar, Bacon, etc). So, for example, I want to search within the Toppings sources but I don't want to see the filters associated with it.

Comment: Hi @Madzik, I'm not sure what you were trying to say. Are the filters the same across different sources? I thought the filters for each source is different.

Comment: They are different. But there are many, many, many filters associated with one source. So let's imagine a situation that I want to search among all of the sources: toppings, cheeses, sauces, but the only filter i want to refine my search by is Cheddar (there will be some sub-filters). This is a pretty difficult example as there are many nested filters, sub-filters, etc.

Comment: woah, then it would look really messy.. let me look around and think a bit if there's better design I'll update my post!